# How can I use a powershell multi-line command as a single line in a command prompt window

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Is there a way to enter at once in the command prompt window?
This code works well without errors when you enter it line by line in the poweshell window.

```
c:\Windows\system32>powershell -command $ACL=New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity ^
   $AccessRule=New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule("User", "Write", "Success") ^
   $ACL.AddAuditRule($AccessRule) ^
   $ACL | Set-Acl C:\Users\User\Desktop\testfile.txt
```

I searched a lot of ways but I couldn't make it in one line.
I tried many different ways, but they all failed.
I want to use this method in the batch-file.
I really need the help of the power users.
Looking forward to your best response.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things here. First - you need the `;` character to separate commands.
Second - look after double quotes and single quotes :)

How to run PS commands with the CLI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_PowerShell_exe?view=powershell-5.1

So - it needs to look like this:

```
C:\Temp>powershell "$ACL=New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity; $AccessRule=New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule('User', 'Write', 'Success');$ACL.AddAuditRule($AccessRule);$ACL | Set-Acl C:\Users\User\Desktop\testfile.txt"
```